# Exported function parameter with private type

Tags: typescript

After installing verison 0.8.1.1 of Typescript I am receiving the following error:
"exported function parameter has or is using private type 'vs'"

In version 0.8.1 I had no problem. Now even if I unistall 0.8.1.1 and reinstall 0.8.1 problem stays. The code is like this:

```
import vs = module("app/framework/ViewStack");
export module Framework {
  export class ViewStacks {
        public static addViewStack( id: string, idContainer: string, 
                                    idParentContainer: string, idLoadingPanel: 
                                    string, loaded: bool ): vs.Framework.ViewStack {
        }
  }
}

In another file

export module Framework {
  export class ViewStack {
  }
}
```

The error is marked in the vs.Framework.ViewStack return type of addViewStack. The error points that vs.Framework.ViewStack is private, but it was imported by the import clause.

By the way I am using Visual Studio Web Express 2012 and the the compiler command is: 
tsc --sourcemap --module amd ...

If I change the return type to any it, of course, works. Nothing was changed and it allways worked.

Every Class or Module that defines an exported variable with type of a class exported by another module the erros occurs.

Can you help me ???

Thans in advance

Comment: You are right. There were alot of question answered by community that I did not maked as an answer. Sorry I have fixed the problem. Thanks

Comment: The problem can be reproduced in the playground with `declare module VIEWSTACK { ... }` and `import vs = module(VIEWSTACK);`

Comment: Yes I know. The playground tells me to use any, I can do that for all type references like this. But it worked before. Then How can I declare an exported variable of a type of an imported module ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

here is the solution http://typescript.codeplex.com/discussions/405800 , you have to "export import"